# How to import an image using Swift UI from Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, swiftui, firebase-storage

im pretty new to swift and have been working on this problem for nearly week now, through multiple iterations and  cant seem to show my downloaded profile picture within my view. I realise there is probably a lot wrong with it, but want to make it work before tidying it up as i have no idea whats going on here and why its not working. Any help would be appreciated!

```
 struct UserProfilePictureStruct: View{

@State var downloadedProfilePicture: UIImage?

func ProfilePictureDownload() {

    let email = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "email")
    let safeEmail = DatabaseManager.safeEmail(emailAddress: email as! String)
    let filename = safeEmail + "_profile_picture.png"
    let path = "images/" + filename
    
    StorageManager.shared.downloadProfilePicture(for: path, completion: {  result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let url): URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {data, _, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("Update: No Image Downloaded ")
                return
            }
            print("Update: Success Image Downloaded 2 ")
            
            downloadedProfilePicture = UIImage(data: data)
            
        })
    case .failure(let error): print("Update: download url error: \(error)")
        
        }
    })
    
}
var body: some View{
      VStack {
          if let profilePicture = downloadedProfilePicture {
              Image(uiImage: profilePicture)
                  .resizable()
                  .scaledToFill()
                  .frame(width: 128, height: 128)
                  .cornerRadius(64)
          } else {
              
              Image(systemName: "eye.slash")
                  .resizable()
                  .scaledToFill()
                  .frame(width: 128, height: 128)
                  .cornerRadius(64)
          }
          
      }.onAppear(perform: ProfilePictureDownload)

  }
```

}

Comment: What happens when you run your current code? Do any of the `print` statements get reached?

Comment: I have print statements that confirm that i have the url from firebase, which comes from outside of this segment. But i don't quite understand why the ones in the above pull through

Comment: Can you clarify what "why the ones in the above pull through" means? Since no one else an run the code that you've provided, we are going to rely on your debugging to help come up with a solution.

Comment: Sorry, here you go: I have print statements that confirm the image URL has been downloaded from Firebase Storage. This returned through "StorageManager.shared.downloadProfilePicture". However, none of the print statements in the code section, that run after URLSession are returned in the terminal. It's almost as if the segment ignores the switch results?

Comment: You aren't showing the code for `downloadProfilePicture`, and if nothing in the callback is getting run, that's likely the source (or one of the sources) of your issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.